# Save chat messages with closed app

Tags: java, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

Good evening!

I'm developing a chat application that looks like WhatsApp. I need the received messages to be saved on the user's mobile device. Until then everything was ok, because I was saving the messages when the user received the push notification on the mobile, but the problem happens when the application is closed because when the application is closed the push notification does not trigger the received push event (I am using the Onesignal to send the push).

I'd like to know how I can do this, ie get a notification and process it even with my closed application. I think it has to do this because Whatsapp does this and also Spotify also does it when I connect the Spotify to another device it automatically forces the opening of the application on my cell phone.

So my question is, how do I handle an event with the application closed or even force it to open according to a particular event?

I'm using the technology of Ionic 1 and Angular.js. For push notification I am using the OneSignal provider.

Thanks in advance for your attention and hope someone can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Maintain a file (I prefer a JSON file) on your device. When a new notification arrives add the message to your file. Read your messages from the file and update when a new notification arrives.

Comment: You cannot rely on push notifications to deliver data; they are not guaranteed.  When your app launches you need to check with your server for any new messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you won't be able to do what you're describing. There is a 'background push' feature introduced in iOS 9 that lets an app receive a payload triggered via push even when it is closed, but that's more for downloading (for example) a new edition of an online magazine, rather than lots of messages.

The difference betwen those two use cases is that if you're subscribed to a magazine, you might want the latest issue to download automatically whilst you have an internet connection, so that you have the issue to read when you're flying/on the train or whatever. A chat app... is pretty useless if you're not connected to the internet anyway, so there's no urgent need to have new messages 'pre-downloaded'

Even if you could do it, I don't think it would be best practice as there's too many scenarios where people won't have internet anyway so you're going to be left without the full message history when a user opens the app (not to mention push notification delivery is not tracked or guaranteed), so you're going to have to do some sort of query when the app launches to download new messages anyway.

If you've got code already that checks and downloads new messages while the app is open, that's great. But if its closed, you'll just need to run some sort of query on launch to download unread messages or something like that